# Top cohomology of the canonical class of a compact non-Kähler manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a complex compact manifold of complex dimension $n$. Let $K_X$ denote its canonical class. Is it true that the cohomology group
$$H^n(X,K_X)$$
is one dimensional?

**Remark.** If $X$ is Kähler then the answer is positive.

Sorry if the question is not of the research level. I am not an expert.

Comment: Yes, that is still one-dimensional.  You can find references in article on complex differential geometry, e.g., Toledo -- Tong, "Duality and intersection theory in complex manifolds, I."  Also it follows directly from the *existence* of the Froehlicher spectral sequence (not its degeneration, which holds when the manifold is Kaehler).  If you look at the terms of the spectral sequence that compute $H^{2n}(X,\mathbb{C})$, the only one that is not automatically zero is $H^n(X,K_X)$.  Now use Poincare duality.

Comment: It also follows  from  Serre duality.

Comment: @DonuArapura: I think this statement is necessary to formulate the Serre duality. Is there a standard reference for the non-Kahler case?

Comment: Duality in the not-necessarily Kaehler case is the subject of the articles of Toledo and Tong.

Comment: Another  reference is Serre's original article "Un théoreme de dualité". He doesn't assume the manifold is Kähler either.

Comment: As Donu says, this is quite classical, and you can find all the results in the book by Griffiths-Harris: first use the Dolbeault Theorem (p.45) $H^n(X,K_X)\cong H^{n,n}_{\overline{\partial}}(X)$, and then use Kodaira-Serre duality (p.102-103). There is no Kähler assumption in any of these.